# Loop on login page no matter what the credentials are

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring Security on my Spring Boot Web project but it's looping on the login page no matter what the credentials are. It is not throwing exceptions, not saying anything is bad, it's just endlessly looping.

Here's my code:

***SecurityConfig Class***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService uDs;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(uDs);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());//no encoding for now
        System.out.println(uDs.toString());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

***MyuserDetailsService Class***

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Searching User ...");
        User user = userRepo.findByPseudo(username);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("No User Found : 404.");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User 404.");
        } else
            System.out.println("User Found !");

        return new PrincipalUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Custom Service";
    }

}
```

***PrincipalUser Class***

```
public class PrincipalUser implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;

    public PrincipalUser(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getPseudo();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

application.properties File

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=WEB-INF/pages/

server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/mytunes?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I'm sure that my custom UserDetailsService class is instantiated but it seems like it's not used ...
Here's Spring's log :

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-05-12 14:26:50.078  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.T.projects.mytunes.MyTunesApplication  : Starting MyTunesApplication on ALEXIS with PID 17808 (E:\SpringTools_WS\MyTunes\target\classes started by Alexis in E:\SpringTools_WS\MyTunes)
2020-05-12 14:26:50.081  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.T.projects.mytunes.MyTunesApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-12 14:26:50.620  INFO 17808 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-12 14:26:50.674  INFO 17808 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 48ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-12 14:26:51.186  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-12 14:26:51.193  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-12 14:26:51.193  INFO 17808 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-05-12 14:26:51.386  INFO 17808 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-05-12 14:26:51.390  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-12 14:26:51.390  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1275 ms
2020-05-12 14:26:51.684  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-12 14:26:51.730  INFO 17808 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-05-12 14:26:51.810  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-12 14:26:51.879  INFO 17808 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-12 14:26:52.190  INFO 17808 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-12 14:26:52.203  INFO 17808 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-05-12 14:26:52.278  WARN 17808 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder       : HHH000457: Joined inheritance hierarchy [org.ThePouil.projects.mytunes.model.music.TrackList] defined explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.  However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the `hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined` setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true)
2020-05-12 14:26:52.979  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-12 14:26:52.985  INFO 17808 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Custom Service
2020-05-12 14:26:53.966  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1aa59698, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3dd750ba, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7b2d58e6, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2b1d1a5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3dfc59c5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5c25daad, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@160546b1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2cacb445, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4641f66c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7d5ef1c3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@395eb363, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1e7cfd49, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@377e90b0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2a6dbb7c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2419fe6f]
2020-05-12 14:26:54.095  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-12 14:26:54.162  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2020-05-12 14:26:54.568  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-12 14:26:54.569  INFO 17808 --- [           main] o.T.projects.mytunes.MyTunesApplication  : Started MyTunesApplication in 4.725 seconds (JVM running for 5.243)
2020-05-12 14:27:06.197  INFO 17808 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-12 14:27:06.197  INFO 17808 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-12 14:27:06.210  INFO 17808 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 13 ms
```

As you can see, "Custom Service" is printed so the object is correctly instantiated. I tried to log in and nothing got printed. So it seems like it's not used, but why?

I'm getting looped using

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
    }
```

If using

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
```

It works, but the log in is done in a pop up, and I want a page with a form.

It seems like the loop bug while using a "form page" was due to my navigator (opera GX). Used chrome and the problem vanished.

Well ... The problem was truly due to user not accepting cookies, not from the navigator itself. But still, Opera GX seems to manage cookies in a strange way.

Comment: As far as I can see you have no security configuration https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration

Comment: I added `@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
 }` but I'm still getting looped. If I add `@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
 }` then it's working fine. But I want a "true" from not just a pop up.

Comment: Please don't add things like 'resolved' to a question title. Either add an **answer** with a solution and accept it after the timeout, or delete your question.